# How to re-use Bootstrap's Modal in Redux

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-redux

Looking at the [React's Bootstrap Document on Modal](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals), it seems that it needs a state to open/close the Modal Window.

Correct me if I am wrong (I am still new to React), but for **stateless Components (or dumb components)** simply means that it only cares about what's feeding into it (via props), hence it does not care about states. This means it is a re-usable component, correct?

If I were to reuse a React-Bootstrap's modal, how would I deal with the showModal state, as shown in the document?

For clarification, check out this [demo from FCC](https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/xVXWag/)

You can see that the Add Recipe and Edit are using the same Modal window.

I've tried to replicate it, but I do not think I am doing correctly:

**src/components/mymodal.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default (props) => {
  const centerText = {
    textAlign : 'center'
  }
  return (
    <Modal show={props.showModal} onHide={props.toggleModal}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title style={centerText}>{props.modalTextTitle}</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
      <form>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="recipeName">Name of Recipe:</label>
          <input
            value={props.recipeName}
            onChange={props.handleRecipeNameChange}
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            id="recipeName" />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="userIngredients">Ingredients:</label>
          <textarea
            placeholder="you can seperate by comma"
            onChange = {props.handleUserIngredientsChange}
            value={props.userIngredients}
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            id="userIngredients" />
        </div>
      </form>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button
        bsStyle="info"
        onClick={props.onClickSubmit}>{props.modalTextTitle}
        </Button> <Button
        bsStyle="danger"
        onClick={props.toggleModal}>Close
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

**src/containers/add_recipe.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { addRecipe } from '../actions/index';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import MyModal from '../components/mymodal';

class AddRecipeButton extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      recipeName: '',
      userIngredients: '',
      showModal: false
    };
    this.onClickSubmit = this.onClickSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleRecipeNameChange = this.handleRecipeNameChange.bind(this)
    this.handleUserIngredientsChange = this.handleUserIngredientsChange.bind(this)
    this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
  }
  toggleModal(){
    this.setState({
        showModal: !this.state.showModal
    });
  }
  onClickSubmit(){
    const splitIngredients = this.state.userIngredients.split(/[ ,]+/)
    this.props.addRecipe([this.state.recipeName, splitIngredients])
    this.toggleModal()
    this.setState({
      recipeName: '',
      userIngredients: ''
    })
  }
  handleRecipeNameChange(event){
    this.setState({recipeName: event.target.value})
  }
  handleUserIngredientsChange(event){
    this.setState({userIngredients: event.target.value})
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          bsStyle="success"
          onClick={this.toggleModal}
          >Add Recipe
        </Button>
        <MyModal
          toggleModal={this.toggleModal}
          showModal={this.state.showModal}
          recipeName={this.state.recipeName}
          userIngredients={this.state.userIngredients}
          handleRecipeNameChange={this.handleRecipeNameChange}
          handleUserIngredientsChange={this.handleUserIngredientsChange}
          onClickSubmit={this.onClickSubmit}
          modalTextTitle={'Add Recipe'}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({addRecipe}, dispatch)
}

export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(AddRecipeButton)
```

You can see that in my **add_recipe.js container** , I have to send many props to .

Answer (score 0):

Dumb, or presentational components usually have no state. If they do, it's a UI state, and not something related to the app's data. In order them to be reused, they can't be connected to the Redux store of the app. You have to keep this strict.

It looks like you are on the right direction, but your `MyModal` is too coupled with the implementation. Use `this.props.children` to pass the modal its content (using `this.props.children` is pretty common in Dumb components). This way, you will be able to reuse it more easily.

Comment: Can you clarify a more on how to implement `this.props.children` in this context?

In my MyModal component, it is getting the content, is it not?

Comment: `MyModal` should use `this.props.children` and act as a wrapper for modals. The content should be passed as children. You can read the official docs here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html